# Issues with Manipulate (or variable assignment)

Tags: manipulate, dataset, pure-function

I am working to take a large manipulator I have built and generalize it, but I keep running into some variable assignment issue.

I made a short example of my issues below:

Set up:

```
dataSet = Dataset[    {
    <|"first" -> 1,
     "second" -> 2, "third" -> 3|>,
    <|"first" -> 3, "second" -> 6, "third" -> 9|>
    }]; 

featureofInterest = "first";

foo2 = ToExpression["#" <> featureofInterest];
```

This works:

```
Manipulate[  foo = dataSet[Select[#first > 2 &]];  foo[All, var],  {var, {"first", "second", "third"}}]
```

But this does not:

```
Manipulate[  foo = dataSet[Select[foo2 > 2 &]];  foo[All, var],  {var, {"first", "second", "third"}}]
```

Even though:

```
foo2 == #first
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `#name` is just a shortcut to `#["name"]` for association, so you may use `Manipulate[foo = dataSet[Select[#[featureofInterest] > 2 &]]; 
 foo[All, var], {var, {"first", "second", "third"}}]`

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html

Comment: Thanks @egwenesedai!!